# More efficient way to set a variable?

Tags: php

I have recently created an if statement script that sets a variable based on what the number represents. After realizing that the script is rather long and that it most likely can be done in a more efficient way I looked on the internet and did not find much results. Here is my script

```
            if ($row[position] == 1){
                $variable = 1;
            } elseif ($row[position] == 2){
                $variable = 1;
            } elseif ($row[position] == 3){
                $variable = 2;
            } elseif ($row[position] == 4){
                $variable = 2;
            } elseif ($row[position] == 5){
                $variable = 3;
            } elseif ($row[position] == 6){
                $variable = 3;
            } elseif ($row[position] == 7){
                $variable = 4;
            } elseif ($row[position] == 8){
                $variable = 4;
            } elseif ($row[position] == 9){
                $variable = 5;
            } elseif ($row[position] == 10){
                $variable = 5;
            } elseif ($row[position] == 11){
                $variable = 6;
            } elseif ($row[position] == 12){
                $variable = 6;
            } elseif ($row[position] == 13){
                $variable = 7;
            } elseif ($row[position] == 14){
                $variable = 7;
            } elseif ($row[position] == 15){
                $variable = 8;
            } elseif ($row[position] == 16){
                $variable = 8;
            }
```

As you can see, it's a pretty basic pattern.

```
1 = 1
2 = 1
3 = 2
4 = 2
5 = 3
6 = 3
```

and so on...

I'm not looking for the work to be done, since it may be a lot, but I simply want to know how I should go about this. Thanks.

Comment: `$variable = ceil($row["position"] / 2)` ?

Comment: This worked perfectly. Now to understand, how come using this ceil gives 3/2 a value of 2 and 4/2 a value of 2? EDIT: I did the research. Ceil rounds up to a floating number. So 3/2 = 1.5 but it rounds up to 2. Thank you very much.

Comment: @RickG. It rounds it up to the next int number! See http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you

```
<?php

    $row["position"] = 4;  //example

    //if (($row["position"] >= 1) && ($row["position"] <= 16) ) -> if you only want to set the variable if it's between 1 and 16 or something else use this if statement
    $variable = ceil($row["position"] / 2);

    echo $variable;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to Rizier123's answer you can use [`round()`](http://php.net/round) with the PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP mode:-

```
$numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];

foreach($numbers as $number){
    echo round($number / 2, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) . "\n";
}
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/iaXr1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use %(mod) operator and divide(/) to do the trick

Here is the trick,

1.Make the position as even. ie if position is already even leave it otherwise add 1 to make it even.

2.Divide the position by 2 to get desire value of the var $variable

```
$pos = $row[position];
if ($pos % 2 == 1) //Check for odd
{ 
     $pos = $pos + 1; //odd+1 =even (converting odd as even)
}

$variable = $pos/2;
```

Example:

$row[position] = 3 => $pos is odd so make it even as 3+1 so 4 => variable=4/2 =>2

$row[position] = 4 => $pos is even so leave as it is => variable=4/2 =>2

$row[position] = 5 => $pos is odd so make it even as 5+1 so 6 => variable=6/2 =>3